# Is there a possible way to make custom graphics for my Corona SDK game?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, cross-platform, coronasdk

I have been developing a game with Corona SDK, but I have run into a little(BIG) problem.  I realized that I do not know how to make graphics for the title-screen and end-screen.  I am hoping to make Flappy Bird-like graphics for the title of the game.  If anyone could help, that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any program like Photoshop or Paint.NET.  If you are using a Windows computer, a paint program should come pre-installed.